# Why is Ruby version 1.9.2 named ruby1.9.1?

Tags: 10.10, ruby

Or in another words, why isn't there a separate ruby-1.9.2 package?

Source info:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ruby1.9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1.9.1 stands for the binary-compatibility version (and as you can read in the package description, ruby 1.9.2 is binary-compatible to ruby 1.9.1).

This is rather confusing - more explanations can be found [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=601526) and [here](http://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=566).

Comment: Thanks for the links. Ugh, that's all I can say for Debian ruby packages maintainers.

Comment: Yeah, most of the ruby devs I know do rvm, binary install on their own, or really goof around with manipulating environment path variables to get gems/includes/versioning to work.  Think metasploit.