# Does anyone have any idea if/when Ubuntu is going to switch the default ruby install from 1.8 train to the 1.9 train?

Tags: default, ruby

I'm kind of hoping it's not going to be a python 2.7/3.0 thing, but I thought I might find someone "in the know".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It's not a Ubuntu decision, its a Debian decision. It's to maintain backwards-comparability, at least until 1.8.7 is end of lifed in June 2012 (for normal bugfixes) and then in June 2013 when security fixes stop (so at time of updating, it is already EOLed). [source](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7) and [source2](https://askubuntu.com/a/24759/6005)
- You can install ruby 1.9.2 via the `ruby1.9.1` package, so its not really that big of a deal - you can also setup a alias so `/usr/bin/ruby` will run `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`. ([or one of the many other options out there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails))